# How can I use Aggregate to Group and Impute Data?

Tags: r, aggregate, missing-data

I need to impute data by grouping across categories and then replacing missing values with the 75th percentile.

I found the aggregate function, which let me do this:

```
GRPAVG = aggregate(INCWAGE ~ AGE + RCE,  data = lps1, mean)
```

Which works beautifully for mean. However, I was unable to get quantile to work here, how can I aggregate across the 75th percentile? IE, I want to group by Age and Race and find the 75th percentile of data in that cross-group.

And furthermore, is there  a way to replace missing values of a different variable with the output of aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

`aggregate` has argument `FUN` (as you know). If function pass on to this argument takes in more arguments, you pass them along through `...`. If you're calculating quantiles, you will want to pass in `probs` argument.

```
data("ChickWeight")

head(ChickWeight)
aggregate(weight ~ Chick + Diet, data = ChickWeight,
          FUN = quantile, probs = 0.75)
```

Comment: Thank you! God, I can be dumb.

Comment: @igiari21 when you stop trying to improve, that's when you need to start worrying. :)